# Changing font in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a little bit unpleasant problem. In my `UITextView` I want to change a size of words, strong and emphasis. It depends on actual index. I am using

```
if(i == 0){
    textV.font = UIFont(name: "Damascus", size: 30)
    text += ("\(pole3[0])\n\(pole2[i]) \(index)\n")
}

else if(i == 3){
    text += ("\(pole3[1])\n\(pole2[i]) \(index)\n")
}

else if(i == 5){
    text += ("\(pole3[2])\n\(pole2[i]) \(index)\n")
}

else if(i == 7){
    text += ("\(pole3[3])\n\(pole2[i]) \(index)\n")
}

else{
    text += ("\(pole2[i]) \(index)\n")
}

textV.font = UIFont(name: "Kailasa", size: 15)
i += 1
```

But this change the font of `UITextView` everytime of all words in my `UITextView`.
Is here any chance to do it? Or I have to use 4 `UITextView`s with different fonts?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're setting `textV.font` if `i == 0`? You're changing `textV.font` explicitly outside of your `if...else` chain no matter what.

Comment: Use `NSAttributedString`, and set the specific font size for specific substrings.

Comment: Yeah, this code is not in full version, i should change the font everytime, when my if condition is true. Because in if conditions are titles. In the rest, that means when i = 1,2,4,6,8,9..... These are not titles and i want  them small and without strong font

Comment: Thanks, I have used NSAttributedString and it works.